# How can I select the job search box in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I've used selenium before but this search box is posing difficult to select.

```html
<div class="jobs-search-box__input jobs-search-box__input--keyword">
  <button class="jobs-search-box__input-icon" type="button" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-489="489">
    <li-icon type="search-icon" role="img" aria-label="Search"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24px" height="24px" x="0" y="0" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" class="artdeco-icon" focusable="false"><path d="M21,19.67l-5.44-5.44a7,7,0,1,0-1.33,1.33L19.67,21ZM10,15.13A5.13,5.13,0,1,1,15.13,10,5.13,5.13,0,0,1,10,15.13Z" class="large-icon" style="fill: currentColor"></path></svg></li-icon>
  </button>

<artdeco-typeahead-deprecated id="ember490" class="ember-view"><artdeco-typeahead-deprecated-input id="ember491" class="ember-view">  <input class="artdeco-typeahead-deprecated-input__ghost-text" placeholder="" aria-label="Search jobs" aria-hidden="true" disabled="" type="text">

<input role="combobox" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-invalid="false" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Search jobs" id="jobs-search-box-keyword-id-ember488" placeholder="Search jobs" type="text">
</artdeco-typeahead-deprecated-input>
<!----><!----></artdeco-typeahead-deprecated></div>
```

I want to be able to send keys. I've been successful in selecting the text box, and my prior searches show up, but then I get an error "element is not interactable", suggesting I need to somehow find the input element.

Comment: @QHarr OP wants to `send keys`. Any reason why [tag:css-selectors] should be replaced with [tag:web-scraping]?

Comment: @QHarr Interacting with the browser through xpath and css is all together a different activity wrt webscraping. What you mentioned is altogether a different opinion sir :)

Comment: @DebanjanB  agreed and changed

Answer (score 2):

I would consider the following css selector. You might not even need the `input` and simply use `[placeholder="Search jobs"]`:

```
input[placeholder="Search jobs"]
```

With a wait

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'input[placeholder="Search jobs"]')))
```

Answer (score 0):

The desired element is an [Ember.js](https://www.emberjs.com/) enabled element so to locate the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[id^='jobs-search-box-keyword-id-'][placeholder='Search jobs']"))).send_keys("Greg Black")
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[starts-with(@id, 'jobs-search-box-keyword-id-') and @placeholder='Search jobs']"))).send_keys("Greg Black")
  ```